# Apple Watch : How to know the screen size?

Tags: apple-watch

I would like to understand how we can know whether the apple watch is 38mm or 42mm so that I can programmatically set the images for UI elements.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I figured it out in `WKInterfaceDevice` class

```
NSLog(@"%@", CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation([WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice].screenBounds));
```

**42mm**
 {
    Height = 195;
    Width = 156;
    X = 0;
    Y = 0;
}

**38mm**
{
    Height = 170;
    Width = 136;
    X = 0;
    Y = 0;
}

Comment: In Swift, you use WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().screenBounds for the same effect.

Comment: Does this size includes the status bar? For an image (for example) that fill the screen, we must subtract the height of the status bar?

Comment: @Markus: That is the number of pixels on the physical screen, so it includes status bars and everything else.